# Angular y Firebase - No se muestran los datos obtenidos de Firestore

Tags: html, angular, firebase, firestore, angularfire

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación Angular que se conecta a Firebase Firestore para recuperar datos de conversaciones de chat. Estoy usando Angular con Firebase y Firestore. He creado un servicio que obtiene los datos de Firestore y luego intento mostrar estos datos en mi plantilla HTML.

El problema es que, aunque puedo ver los datos correctamente en la consola y en la pestaña Network de las herramientas de desarrollo del navegador (lo que sugiere que los datos se obtienen de Firestore correctamente), no se muestran en la plantilla. La plantilla parece estar en blanco.

Aquí está mi código:

Servicios.ts

```
getConversationsWithDetails() {
    return this.afs.collection('conversations').valueChanges().pipe(
        switchMap((conversations: any[]) => {
            if (!conversations || conversations.length === 0) {
                return of([]);
            }

            // Obtener los IDs de cliente de las conversaciones.
            const customerIds = conversations.map(conversation => conversation.customerID);

            // Obtener clientes por sus IDs.
            const customersQuery = this.afs.collection('customers', ref => ref.where('uid', 'in', customerIds)).valueChanges();

            return combineLatest([of(conversations), customersQuery]);
        }),
        switchMap(([conversations, customers]: any) => {
            if (!conversations || conversations.length === 0 || !customers || customers.length === 0) {
                return of([]);
            }

            // Obtener los últimos mensajes por el lastMessageID.
            const messageQueries = conversations.map(conversation => {
                const conversationRef = this.afs.doc(`conversations/${conversation.uid}`);
                console.log('LastMessageID:', conversation.lastMessageID);

                const messageRef = conversationRef.collection('messages').doc(conversation.lastMessageID);
                return messageRef.valueChanges();
            });

            return combineLatest([of(conversations), of(customers), combineLatest(messageQueries)]);
        }),
        map(([conversations, customers, messages]: any) => {
            // Aquí tienes todas las conversaciones, clientes y sus últimos mensajes.
            // Puedes combinar y procesar los datos según tus necesidades.
            return {
                conversations,
                customers,
                messages
            };
        })
    );
}
```

Y la estructura del JSON a iterar

Dentro de cada idCliente(key customerId) estan las conversaciones, la idea es desplegar las conversaciones por cliente y mostrar el ultimo mensaje asi como algunos datos del cliente

```
{
    "hHu0IUMeZEkRncn3BDxM": {
        "4PGEdGZhGx3nt6dSOg5J": {
            "conversacion": {
                "ticketID": "OURssQ6dVdiLu9lID1PE",
                "channelID": "MVMvPJ3TAb0dwydLy1ht",
                "isClosed": false,
                "accountServiceID": "qhaVePBpUdx3yCEzx2ez",
                "customerID": "hHu0IUMeZEkRncn3BDxM",
                "uid": "4PGEdGZhGx3nt6dSOg5J",
                "userIDs": [],
                "lastMessageID": "CLzqYQ3cILjbYYmFJEA3",
                "read": false,
                "createdAt": {
                    "seconds": 1697841361,
                    "nanoseconds": 655000000
                },
                "status": true,
                "readDateTime": {
                    "seconds": 1697841361,
                    "nanoseconds": 655000000
                }
            },
            "cliente": {
                "email": null,
                "hasTicketActive": true,
                "createdAt": {
                    "seconds": 1697776972,
                    "nanoseconds": 177000000
                },
                "organizationIDs": {},
                "fullName": null,
                "channelsID": [
                    "MVMvPJ3TAb0dwydLy1ht"
                ],
                "uid": "hHu0IUMeZEkRncn3BDxM",
                "phoneNumber": "50489854230",
                "lastChannelID": "MVMvPJ3TAb0dwydLy1ht",
                "lastOrganizationID": ""
            },
            "mensaje": [
                {
                    "createdAt": {
                        "seconds": 1697841466,
                        "nanoseconds": 308000000
                    },
                    "userIDs": [],
                    "customerID": "hHu0IUMeZEkRncn3BDxM",
                    "readDateTime": {
                        "seconds": 1697841466,
                        "nanoseconds": 308000000
                    },
                    "read": false,
                    "content": "se deberia guardar en id 4PGEdGZhGx3nt6dSOg5J",
                    "attachment": [],
                    "typeMessage": "text",
                    "channelID": "MVMvPJ3TAb0dwydLy1ht",
                    "ticketID": "OURssQ6dVdiLu9lID1PE",
                    "messageStatus": "send",
                    "status": true
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "6hsIktIF3PtcxOqcWjUG": {
        "L98Z4laKYjiPm6a4HqX4": {
            "conversacion": {
                "status": true,
                "customerID": "6hsIktIF3PtcxOqcWjUG",
                "lastMessageID": "RcJ21hOxFJnb0hh95FcG",
                "userIDs": [],
                "readDateTime": {
                    "seconds": 1697842197,
                    "nanoseconds": 429000000
                },
                "isClosed": false,
                "ticketID": "oWVhieyqeL4jPoxbZuWV",
                "uid": "L98Z4laKYjiPm6a4HqX4",
                "createdAt": {
                    "seconds": 1697842197,
                    "nanoseconds": 429000000
                },
                "channelID": "MVMvPJ3TAb0dwydLy1ht",
                "read": false,
                "accountServiceID": "qhaVePBpUdx3yCEzx2ez"
            },
            "cliente": {
                "phoneNumber": "50487564123",
                "organizationIDs": [
                    "qhaVePBpUdx3yCEzx2ez"
                ],
                "email": null,
                "uid": "6hsIktIF3PtcxOqcWjUG",
                "fullName": null,
                "lastChannelID": "MVMvPJ3TAb0dwydLy1ht",
                "channelsID": [
                    "MVMvPJ3TAb0dwydLy1ht"
                ],
                "createdAt": {
                    "seconds": 1697842197,
                    "nanoseconds": 429000000
                },
                "lastOrganizationID": "qhaVePBpUdx3yCEzx2ez",
                "hasTicketActive": true
            },
            "mensaje": [
                {
                    "customerID": "6hsIktIF3PtcxOqcWjUG",
                    "read": false,
                    "uid": "RcJ21hOxFJnb0hh95FcG",
                    "userIDs": [],
                    "status": true,
                    "ticketID": "oWVhieyqeL4jPoxbZuWV",
                    "channelID": "MVMvPJ3TAb0dwydLy1ht",
                    "messageStatus": "send",
                    "content": "se deberia guardar en id 4PGEdGZhGx3nt6dSOg5J",
                    "attachment": [],
                    "readDateTime": {
                        "seconds": 1697842197,
                        "nanoseconds": 429000000
                    },
                    "createdAt": {
                        "seconds": 1697842197,
                        "nanoseconds": 429000000
                    },
                    "typeMessage": "text"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "IcKWuLhCVgrccUeyqBpY": {
        "Y0igxPUoun5ZT3Xpnf86": {
            "conversacion": {
                "uid": "Y0igxPUoun5ZT3Xpnf86",
                "readDateTime": {
                    "seconds": 1697842318,
                    "nanoseconds": 615000000
                },
                "createdAt": {
                    "seconds": 1697842318,
                    "nanoseconds": 615000000
                },
                "channelID": "MVMvPJ3TAb0dwydLy1ht",
                "status": true,
                "ticketID": "Y8D7jF9iSiVNpooKOXse",
                "userIDs": [],
                "read": false,
                "accountServiceID": "qhaVePBpUdx3yCEzx2ez",
                "isClosed": false,
                "customerID": "IcKWuLhCVgrccUeyqBpY",
                "lastMessageID": "CCDsd7GBbsmH6IFMTUdb"
            },
            "cliente": {
                "lastOrganizationID": "qhaVePBpUdx3yCEzx2ez",
                "fullName": null,
                "lastChannelID": "MVMvPJ3TAb0dwydLy1ht",
                "uid": "IcKWuLhCVgrccUeyqBpY",
                "createdAt": {
                    "seconds": 1697842318,
                    "nanoseconds": 615000000
                },
                "email": null,
                "phoneNumber": "504333333333",
                "hasTicketActive": true,
                "organizationIDs": [
                    "qhaVePBpUdx3yCEzx2ez"
                ],
                "channelsID": [
                    "MVMvPJ3TAb0dwydLy1ht"
                ]
            },
            "mensaje": [
                {
                    "read": false,
                    "ticketID": "Y8D7jF9iSiVNpooKOXse",
                    "customerID": "IcKWuLhCVgrccUeyqBpY",
                    "uid": "CCDsd7GBbsmH6IFMTUdb",
                    "messageStatus": "send",
                    "channelID": "MVMvPJ3TAb0dwydLy1ht",
                    "readDateTime": {
                        "seconds": 1697842318,
                        "nanoseconds": 615000000
                    },
                    "userIDs": [],
                    "status": true,
                    "typeMessage": "text",
                    "createdAt": {
                        "seconds": 1697842318,
                        "nanoseconds": 615000000
                    },
                    "attachment": [],
                    "content": "Se dberua crear en L98Z4laKYjiPm6a4HqX4"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Componente TS

```
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnDestroy, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, forkJoin, take, takeUntil, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AllChat, Chat, Profile } from '../mensajes.types';
import { MensajesService } from '../mensajes.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'chat-chats',
    templateUrl: './chats.component.html',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class ChatsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    chats: Chat[];
    drawerComponent: 'profile' | 'new-chat';
    drawerOpened: boolean = false;
    filteredChats: Chat[];
    profile: Profile;
    allChats: AllChat[] = [];

    conversations: any;
    conversationsByClient: { [clienteID: string]: any[] } = {}; // Inicializar como objeto vacío

    conversationsByClientArray: any[] = [];
    customerId: string = "";
    clienteInfo: any;

    private _unsubscribeAll: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    constructor(
        private _chatService: MensajesService,
        private _changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    }

    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // @ Lifecycle hooks
    // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * On init
     */
    ngOnInit(): void {

        this._chatService.getConversationsWithDetails().subscribe((data: any) => {
            console.log('data', data);
            // Aquí puedes acceder a los datos completos, que incluyen conversaciones, clientes y mensajes.
            // Puedes asignar estos datos a variables locales del componente o realizar cualquier otro procesamiento necesario.
    
            const organizedData = {};
            const pushData: any[] = []

            for (const conversation of data.conversations) {
                const customerID = conversation.customerID;
                const conversationID = conversation.uid;

                // Crear una estructura si aún no existe.
                if (!organizedData[customerID]) {
                    organizedData[customerID] = {};
                }
                if (!organizedData[customerID][conversationID]) {
                    organizedData[customerID][conversationID] = {};
                }

                // Agregar información de la conversación.
                organizedData[customerID][conversationID].conversacion = conversation;

                // Agregar información del cliente a la conversación.
                organizedData[customerID][conversationID].cliente = data.customers.find(customer => customer.uid === customerID);

                // Obtener los mensajes relacionados con esta conversación.
                organizedData[customerID][conversationID].mensaje = data.messages.filter(message => message.customerID === customerID);

            }

            // Ahora tienes un objeto `organizedData` en el que puedes acceder a los datos como se describe en la estructura anterior.

            this.conversations = organizedData;
            console.log(organizedData);
            console.log('this.', this.conversations);

        });

        // Profile
        this._chatService.profile$
            .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
            .subscribe((profile: Profile) => {
                console.log('profile', profile);
                this.profile = profile;

                // Mark for check
                this._changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
            });


    }

    //On destroy
    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        // Unsubscribe from all subscriptions
        this._unsubscribeAll.next(null);
        this._unsubscribeAll.complete();
    }



    // Obtener el ultimo mensaje

    getLastMessage(conversationId: string, lastMessageId: string) {
        return this._chatService.getMessageLastID(conversationId, lastMessageId)
    }

    // Obtener Info del cliente

    getClientIds(conversations: any): string[] {
        console.log('conversations gett', conversations);
        this._changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
        return Object.keys(conversations);
    }

    getObjectKeys(obj: any): string[] {
        return Object.keys(obj);
    }

    //Open the new chat sidebar
    openNewChat(): void {
        this.drawerComponent = 'new-chat';
        this.drawerOpened = true;

        // Mark for check
        this._changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
    }


    //Open the profile sidebar
    openProfile(): void {
        this.drawerComponent = 'profile';
        this.drawerOpened = true;

        // Mark for check
        this._changeDetectorRef.markForCheck();
    }
}
```

La plantilla HTML

```
        <div class="flex-auto overflow-y-auto">
            <ng-container *ngIf="conversations">
                <ng-container
                    *ngFor="let clienteID of conversations | keyvalue">
                    <div
                        class="border-b border-gray-200 dark:border-gray-600 p-4">
                        <div class="flex items-center space-x-4">
                            <mat-icon>person</mat-icon>
                            <div class="flex-1">
                                <p class="text-base font-semibold">Cliente
                                    ID: {{ clienteID.key }}</p>
                                <ng-container
                                    *ngFor="let conversationID of clienteID.value | keyvalue">
                                    <a>
                                        <div
                                            class="flex items-center space-x-4">
                                            <div class="flex-1">
                                                <p
                                                    class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Conversación
                                                    ID: {{
                                                    conversationID.key
                                                    }}</p>
                                                <p
                                                    class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Información
                                                    de la conversación:
                                                    {{
                                                    conversationID.value.conversacion.uid
                                                    | json }}</p>

                                                <p
                                                    class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Información
                                                    del cliente: {{
                                                    conversationID.value.cliente.phoneNumber
                                                    | json }}</p>

                                                <ng-container
                                                    *ngFor="let mensaje of conversationID.value.mensaje">
                                                    <p
                                                        class="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">Mensaje:
                                                        {{ mensaje |
                                                        json }}</p>
                                                </ng-container>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </a>
                                </ng-container>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
```

He comprobado que los datos se asignan correctamente a la propiedad conversations en mi componente y que las propiedades en mi plantilla HTML coinciden con las propiedades de los datos.

He intentado cambiar la forma en que me suscribo a los servicios para la obtencio de la data en tiempo real, pero el problema persiste. Llevo desde ayer con esto y no se que podria estar pasando, yo creo que es que los datos llegan despues de que se inicia el componente no hallo otra explicacion

¿Alguien ha enfrentado un problema similar o tiene alguna idea de lo que podría estar saliendo mal? Cualquier ayuda será apreciada.

Gracias de antemano.